# Why can't I align a canvas for my game with "anchor" or "justify"? They both throw an error

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, game-development, python-3.8

I'm making a game called "RuntDeale" (an UnderTale fangame), and I moved profiles on Windows, and accidentally deleted my original code. I tried to remake it, but when I tried to anchor the canvas I have, it throws `TclError: unknown option "-anchor"`, and it doesn't work.

I want to anchor the canvas because of the way coordinates changed.
I've also tried using `justify`, but it throws practically the same error.

Here's a snippet of code:

```py
CTX = tk.Canvas(
    WIND, highlightthickness=0,
    bd=0, bg="black",
    width=500, height=400,
    anchor=tk.NW
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is clear: anchor isn't a  valid option for the canvas widget. Neither is `justify`. Why do you think it's a valid option, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @BryanOakley Because I thought I remembered using in my implementation the last time I tried coding the game.
Maybe I'm mistaken, but, what did I mean to apply "anchor" to?

Comment: @BryanOakley I figured it out. Apparently the creators of `tk` / `tcl` thought it would be a good idea to mix where you can apply certain settings.
I actually wanted to apply "-anchor" to the image.

(Editors note: What was the `Tcl`/`Tk` team thinking??)

Comment: _"the creators of tk / tcl thought it would be a good idea to mix where you can apply certain settings"_ - well, yes. You can't just pick from a big pile of attributes and apply them to whatever you want. Adding an `anchor` option to a Canvas makes no sense. Why would they have you specify `anchor` for the canvas in order to affect an image inside the canvas? What if you wanted more than one image anchored to different positions? This isn't a design flaw.

Comment: @BryanOakley I like your logic, but, wouldn't it also be convenient to anchor everything in advance, when all you want is "normal" coordinates.
Because, again, the problem was `(0, 0)` was not actually the top-left, it was a little past that, so only 1/4 of the object I wanted to show was being displayed. When I anchored it, it was fine.
Again, I'm just saying it'd be more convinient for the type of programming **I** want to do, even if it isn't the best, I just wish there was an easier version of `tkinter`.
You can't tell me you aren't annoyed w/ at least one part of its design.

Comment: No, because what is normal to you isn’t normal for others. Since `anchor` only applies to some canvas objects, it makes the most sense to make it an attribute of only the objects it applies to.

Comment: Personally, I’ve used maybe a dozen GUI toolkits over three+ decades, and I’ve never found any other one to be as well designed and easy to use as the tk toolkit. There may be one or two annoyances, but for me there are far fewer than other toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I wanted was to apply the "anchor" property to the image itself.